# How to call a structure variable?

Tags: matlab, structure

I am working with parallel execution in MATLAB. How can I access the data inside Structure inside Class ?
This is the code :

```
>> clust

clust =

   Lab 1: class = struct, size = [1  2]
   Lab 2: class = struct, size = [1  2]
   Lab 3: class = struct, size = [1  2]
   Lab 4: class = struct, size = [1  2]

>> [clust{1}]

ans = 

1x2 struct array with fields:

    Data
```

Comment: what about regular structure assignment using dot notation?

Comment: Hi Benoit, Thank you very much for your answer. Please could you explain what you mean "regular structure assignment using dot notation" because I used this code:

Comment: >> [K{1}]

ans =

   86.5000   36.5000
   60.5000  113.5000  it is working , but with Class of Structure of Variable it does not work. Actually, I am new in MATALB, so I do apologies if it is silly question!

Comment: @ammaralabdalazeez you might want to get more creative with question names. Three questions with the exact same name are not very distinguishable.

Comment: @ammaralabdalazeez also, if you're new to matlab, first learn the syntax in serial, then try to parallellise it. Don't try both at the same time.

Comment: What is `K`? Also, by dot notation I mean using `clust.Data` for example to access the field named `Data` in the structure named `clust`. Moreover, if you are working with structures I recommend reading [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) topic on Mathworks website for a start.

Comment: Hi Benoit, K is a class like this: >> K
 
K =
 
   Lab 1: class = double, size = [2  2]
   Lab 2: class = double, size = [2  2]
   Lab 3: class = double, size = [2  2]
   Lab 4: class = double, size = [2  2]
 and its value is >> [K{1}]

ans =

    87   110
    64    33

Comment: but when I write this >> clust
 
clust =
 
   Lab 1: class = struct, size = [1  2]
   Lab 2: class = struct, size = [1  2]
   Lab 3: class = struct, size = [1  2]
   Lab 4: class = struct, size = [1  2]
 and >> clust{1}

ans = 

1x2 struct array with fields:

    Data

Comment: and when I write this >> clust.Data
Error using Composite/subsref (line 12)
Dot invocation is not allowed for Composites, use the functional form instead.
 or >> [clust.Data]
Error using Composite/subsref (line 12)
Dot invocation is not allowed for Composites, use the functional form instead.

Answer (score 1):

`clust` is a `Composite`, which behaves a little like a `cell` array, so using `{}` indexing is correct to extract the value from a single worker. Those values are arrays of `struct`, and can be accessed in the usual way. So, it should work to do this

```
V1 = clust{1};
D = V1(1).Data
```

Comment: Hi Edric, thank you very much for your answer. In fact, it is working now, that is amazing. Thanks again.